# Can't Change the default python to 3.7 in ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: python3, python-2.7

I am not very experienced at Linux but I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 and I am trying to use Python 3 and the default is Python 2. I spent a lot of time reading how to configure Ubuntu to run Python 3 but I felt to do it.  Can anyone please help me? I used these commands but nothing works...

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --list python
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7
```

Comment: Don't do change default python. It will break many things.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python explains Python 3 is the default, not 2.7.

Comment: Might be a classic confusion: `python` *always* refers to Python2 (in accordance with [PEP394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)). Don't change that behavior in Ubuntu, or you will break things. However, `python` (py2) is NOT installed by default in newer releases of Ubuntu anymore anyway. Instead, `python3` is installed, and important parts of your system (like apt) rely upon it. Don't change it either.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the default Python interpreter is probably no good idea, as system tools could depend on the Python version.

As Python 2 support officially ends at the beginning of 2020, it is certainly a good idea to use Python 3 when you create new projects.

In order to use Python 3, just enter `python3` in the terminal.

There is no need to change the default behavior.

Comment: Their must more problem than python 3 issues with ubuntu-19.10 because now the terminal is not responding and I restarted my PC ...

Comment: Assuming all OP wants is to point the command `python` to `python3`, wouldn't modifying `.bashrc` suffice? My understanding is that `.bashrc` is only executed in interactive shells, not scripts and such.

Comment: @user1016220 You mentioned terminals not starting; your text terminals (ctrl+alt+f4 etc) should work normally (they don't use python), however some GUI terminals do use python so if you change default behavior in regards python - some GUI terminals may no longer start.  That's why you got breakage warnings.   You'll just need to use text terminals to undo whatever you did.